# Override Angular HttpClient without cloning

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

Is there any way to add the 'withCredentials' option to the request that goes to the server by default?

We just don't want to clone the object by an interceptor and want to override the HttpClient by creating another class / service extending the HttpClient.

Comment: So did you try creating another class extending the client with the behaviour you describe? What happened?

Comment: Yeah, that's the first we do. We see that there is a request() method that seems to wrap all the others (put, post, get ...). But we took the exact same thing and tried to override, but the compiler doesn't accept it

Comment: Please give a [mcve] illustrating that, then.

Comment: still don't understand why not use http interceptor? that's whats it buildt for. In my projects I use interceptor to default add JWT tokens (Bearer) with out going requests to the server